# Why does the linear model work in image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-algebra

I'm heavily studying machine learning on all its mathematic foundations. It's perfectly clear to me that it works mathematically, but there is one thing that I cannot get.

My question is simple as that:

Why does the linear model work while training an image-to-character (using, for example, notMNIST dataset as training source) classification model? For what I know, using a linear model, we are saying that an output is a function a linear function of an input + a bias parameter. But I already know that a linear model doesn't work well for other kinds of applications.

So, why does it work for this and not for others?

Comment: What linear classification model are you referencing?  Linear models certainly don't work well in the image-processing areas in which I work.  You've made a general statement that isn't universally true; can you qualify this to a useful question?

Comment: For example classifying characters using notMNIST dataset as training and validation source. I've edited the question.

Comment: Okay ... what other applications are you using for comparison?

Comment: I'm not saying that it's the best model! But it's incredilble, to my eyes, that is working... I've trained a simple model, using TensorFlow, and performance the test set are near 90%. Maybe it's a shame compared to other models, but... I cannot believe that, and I'm not getting the meaning of this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model complexity varies with the problem being solved.  MNIST is a very simple case, and *happens* to be susceptible to linear combination, due to the narrow range of both inputs (face-on numbers in gray scale) and outputs (one of 10 digits) and their inherent differences.  For instance, `4` and `9` have different connectivity, a property that linear combination can discern.  Given enough nodes, an MNIST model can be trained into the upper 90s with little problem.

Consider instead the ILSVRC image set, where discrimination depends on color, stance, relative proportion of subject parts (e.g. wolfhound vs poodle), and other characteristics both small and large.  These require scaling, generalization, adaptability to interfering objects (e.g. bushes in the foreground) and other properties.  A sufficiently large linear network would likely differentiate ten classes reasonably well, but would not make the fine discrimination of 1000.

I just found this [blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-10-Visualizing-MNIST/) that helps highlight some of the complexity of MNIST ... and its simplification.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that it works just because the problem is very simple and "well conditioned", am I right? And it works just almost by accident... Where I can find more on "connectivity" to understand why 4 and 9 have a different one and why linear models can discern? In the case of ILSRVC, what kind of models do you use?

Comment: Right.  I don't know that there is a simple paper on *why* the topology of our Arabic numerals makes them susceptible to linear training.  For ILSVRC ... actually, you should just do a browser search.  If it helps, use the term "ImageNet" as well ... this is a large area of research, and I don't want this to turn into a tutorial on image processing -- that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications.